# Joi validation feathersjs

Tags: feathersjs, joi

I have a feathersjs API with a `messages service`. I want to validate the message model with `feathers-hooks-validate-joi` module.

Here is my `messages-hooks.js` file:

```
const validate = require('feathers-hooks-validate-joi');
const schema = require('./messages.validator');

module.exports = {
  before: {
    create: [validate.form(schema)],
    //others method fields
  },
  after: {...},
  error: {...}
};
```

Here is my `messages.validator.js` file:

```
const Joi = require('joi');

const schema = Joi.object().keys({
  name: Joi.string().trim().min(2).required(),
  text: Joi.string().trim().min(2).required()
});

module.exports = {schema};
```

When I try to post a message via curl:

`curl 'http://localhost:3030/messages/' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-binary '{ "name": "Hello", "text": "World" }'`

I receive this error message:

```
{
  "name": "BadRequest",
  "message": "Invalid data",
  "code": 400,
  "className": "bad-request",
  "data": {},
  "errors": {
    "name": "\"name\" is not allowed",
    "text": "\"text\" is not allowed"
  }
}
```

Am I missing something? Am I using the feathers hook correctly?

Answer (score 1):

```
module.exports = {schema};
```

This should be:

```
module.exports = schema;
```

shouldn't it?

Alternatively, your require statement should be changed to:

```
const {schema } = require('./messages.validator');
```

Comment: When I try your solution I got this error message: `{
  "name": "GeneralError",
  "message": "Cannot read property 'convert' of undefined",
  "code": 500,
  "className": "general-error",
  "data": {},
  "errors": {}
}`